# Actualizar contador de participantes en una base de datos

Tags: php, contador

estoy tratando de realizar un código en php que seguramente es sencillo pero no encuentro la forma de resolverlo.
Estoy intentando eliminar a un participante de una competencia y una vez eliminado el contador de participantes se realice nuevamente, por ejemplo, tengo 5 participantes y elimino al número 3, quiero que se realice otra vez el contador de participantes asignándoles un número del 1 al 4.
No encuentro la forma de hacerlo todo en el mismo archivo de eliminar, agradecería si me pueden ayudar. 
Sé que debo enviar los datos a través de un array pero no se me ocurre la manera de generarlo en modo de contador.
Aclaro que el usuario se elimina correctamente, el problema surge al querer asignar a los participantes un nuevo número de participante

indice.php

```
<form class="" action="torneos/eliminar.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $recorreP['id']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="grupo[]" value="<?php echo $_GET['id_grupo']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="grupo1[]" value="<?php echo $_GET['id_grupo']; ?>">
   <input type="submit" name="eliminar" value="ELIMINAR">
</form>
```

eliminar.php

```
$grupoArray = $_POST['grupo'];
$grupo1Array = $_POST['grupo1'];
$idArray = $_POST['id'];

            $eliminar = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM usersxgrupos WHERE id_grupo=:grupo && id=:id");
            foreach ($grupoArray as $es => $val) {
                  $grupo = $val;
                  $id = $idArray[$es];

                  $eliminar->bindParam(':grupo', $grupo );

                  $eliminar->bindParam(':id', $id);
                  try {
                      $eliminar->execute();
                 } catch (PDOException $e) {
                   die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
                }}


//AQUI ES DONDE NO SÉ COMO OPERAR Y PENSÉ EN UN BUCLE PERO NO SÉ COMO UTILIZARLO, $a VENDRÍA A SER UNA ESPECIE DE "CONTADOR", ES SOLO UNA REFERENCIA A MI PROBLEMA

$renumera = $conn->prepare("UPDATE usersxgrupos SET jugador=:jugador WHERE id_grupo=:idgrupo");
  foreach ($grupo1Array as $es1 => $val1) {
        $grupo = $val1;
        echo $a;

        $renumera->bindParam(':idgrupo', $grupo );

        $renumera->bindParam(':jugador', $a);

        try {
            $renumera->execute();
       } catch (PDOException $e) {
         die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
      }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿cuál es la razón por la qué se actualiza *jugador*? y ¿con base en que es reasignado, es un tablero de posición, es un identificador, o que papel juega esta columna? Se me ocurre que mejor podrías hacerlo a nivel base de datos a través de un trigger

Comment: Es una base de datos en la cual a cada participante se le asigna un valor del 1 al 8 según el grupo en el que participan. Es un valor de importancia a cada usuario, el 1 sería el más importante, luego el 2 y así. Debo investigar trigger lo he usado poco y nada

Comment: Entiendo que se le va asignando a cómo van entrando al juego; y cuando se sale un jugador, los números por debajo de él se reasignan, con un -1, e.g. si sale el 4, los números del 5-8 pasarán a ser del 4-7 respectivamente. ¿Algo así?

Comment: Claro, esa es la idea. Supongo que esta es la forma más sencilla de resolverla, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos formas en las que se puede realizar la actualización de los valores de esa columna:

1. [Trigger de base de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigger_(base_de_datos)), dependiendo si el motor de base de datos que se está utilizando lo soporta.
2. La actualización basada en el ciclo, ejecutándose este ya sea en el servidor web o en el motor de base de datos.

También puedo agregar una tercera opción, que a mi parecer pudiera ser más efectiva, tendría que analizarse con base en el contexto y el panorama general de la aplicación; la opción sería no almacenar ese dato en la base de datos.

Expongo.

#### Opción 1

El trigger se debe ejecutar al realizarse la eliminación del jugador y dentro de su procedimiento deberá realizar la actualización del dato para todos aquellos registros donde el valor de jugador sea mayor que el que tenía el reciente eliminado.

#### Opción 2

Mismo que el trigger pero en este caso la ejecución se realiza a través del conector (me parece que ví que era PDO) y los ciclos se iterarian del lado del servidor web.

#### Detalles de actualización

Para cualquiera de las dos opciones, ya sea que la actualización se realice en automático (trigger) o manualmente (en el servidor web), se puede seguir la lógica siguiente:

1. Se almacena en una variable el valor de jugador, del registro que fue eliminado.
2. Se actualizan todos los registros donde jugador sea mayor que el eliminado sustrayendole 1 a su valor actual, e.g. si jugador eliminado es 3, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 4, etc.

```sql
SELECT @eliminado := 3; # Aquí obtener el valor del eliminado

DELETE FROM jugadores WHERE jugador = @eliminado;

# Actualización de columna jugador
UPDATE jugadores SET jugador = jugador - 1
    WHERE jugador > @eliminado;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fXjessiiMCQcmwwe5xYqsQ/2

La tercera opción que menciona resulta en no almacenar ese valor, sino calcularlo cada que se presenta la información, a menos que este proceso sea más costoso que el hecho de realizar las actualizaciones; es por esto, que se sugiere su análisis contemplando el panorama completo y alcance de la aplicación.

Comment: Recién veo la respuesta me ha servido tu recomendación de utilizar un trigger! Muchas gracias